# Image path in CSS adds '/' (i.e. Slash) to the begining

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am assigning imagepath to background-image property of CSS using js code.
My code is as mentioned below.

```js
backgroundImage:"url("+b.img+")",backgroundPosition:-i*b.index+"px 0px"
```

and the related html code is something like below:

```
 <div id="wPaint" style="position:relative; width:500px; height:200px; background-color:#7a7a7a; margin:70px auto 20px auto;"></div>
```

My question is when I use above code, all the image with proper background position is seen. But when I use above HTML code twice, the background-image propety adds '/' (i.e. slash) in the beginning of the url path and the image is not displayed.

It happens everytime I use this code it adds one '/' to the image url.

I really don't understand why this happens. Please help me out.

Comment: It shouldn't do that. Presumably, `b.img` already includes that `/`. You should provide a real [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
backgroundImage:"url(/"+b.img+")",backgroundPosition:-i*b.index+"px 0px"
```